# Inputting Opportunity for Leads

Tags: opportunity, leads

Pardon my question, which I'm sure is quite basic due to my level of knowledge.

In my industry I respond and quote quite frequently to RFQ's (Request for Quote). They will become an Account only if our quote is accepted. There is zero chance for future follow-up or future business due to the nature of the industry. The problems I'm seeing are:

1. I can't assign detailed information in the opportunity
2. I can't assign potential value to a lead.

Here are my must haves:

1. I do not want to input them as an account.
2. I do want to forecast the opportunity an be able to see the pipeline.
3. Need to assign opportunities to leads...not accounts.

What is the best way to handle this in Lightning? Am I missing something, somewhere, which makes this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you willing to convert them to Accounts after all, perhaps with record type = Prospect? (that would allow you to relax some validation rules etc if needed). You could have an Opportunity, Quote, Contract, Order, all this standard stuff. Sure, it'd be a waste of space if you don't win the deal but on the other hand - that's what "Closed Lost" status is for. How are your sales reps tracked? Even if it's ultimately a fail an Opp would show some work happened (and if storage is really a concern - you probably periodically delete these failed Leads / Quotes anyway).
2. Opportunity can exist without an account (that's standard SF, if you have account mandatory then it's your own config). It's considered private (similar to private Contacts & Tasks), no amount of sharing can make it visible to non-sysadmins, but you could have that. Just slap a Lead lookup and you're good to go.
3. Or perhaps create some dummy accounts, one per department? country? and assign opportunities to them. It's not great because it might cause data skew problems once you have > 10K records related to one parent - but it's also an option. Even better if you got these leads from say a Partner Account, then linking them there sounds like nice idea.
4. Last but not least - are there some "groups of leads", businesses with similar circumstances? Or situations where quote will be more or less identical? Do you have some standard scenarios or maybe events ("Spring sale 2018")? I'm trying to lead you (heh, "lead") towards Campaign and Campaign Member object.

   - opps can list a Campaign as a source
   - Campaign Members can be Contacts or Leads

So a campaign could have a default Opp (and that opp perhaps dozens of quotes) and would have Leads assigned to it. I think it'd be a b*tch to report on (Campaign as parent + 2 related lists sounds like joined reports) but it's something.

5. Well, why not... Why don't you use Tasks under Leads to track "opportunities"?

Have a look at the [data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm) and see how much standard functionality you're missing out with the requirement to not use Accounts. I mean, you're paying for it anyway...

Comment: I think the solution #1 you mentioned above will have to work best. I didn't think of creating a new record type of say "Prospect" to distingush them from other accounts. Thank you